# 53 puzzles are going to lose their images some time in the next 6-8 weeks - let's find a time to fix them

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange is switching over to [HTTPS-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only). While this is a positive change that I commend SE for undergoing, it does mean something pretty specific for us. Action item for SE:

> Rebake remaining posts with HTTP images, so that images linking to HTTP addresses will become links - most of those are dead anyway. This will be a HTML baking change, so no Markdown will be affected, but it'll remove any mixed content even when viewing old revisions.

Soooo... we're going to lose those images. I'd rather we don't lose them. These questions need to be edited in preparation to retain those images. [Here's a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/430352/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2014-05-14&EndDate=2017-03-08) that shows you what the list of questions is - thankfully, there are only 53 of them, far less than I expected. Still not insignificant, though. (I'm keeping a backup as a CSV.)

We have a couple options for cleaning this up:

- We can edit them all at once.
- We can edit them slowly over time, editing 2-4 a day over the next few weeks.

Editing them slowly is *more* likely to lose interest, or take some serious dedication and restraint on the part of Friendly Citizens. But unless we truly dedicate to it, there's a possibility it may not be done before the change. (I'd be happy to help with it, too.)

Editing them all at once is likely to decimate attention to the front page, so we'd want to do it during off-hours. But it does get it out of the way all at once.

If you're in favor of either option, please post an answer indicating why! If you're in favor of editing them all at once, please suggest a time and/or day you think would be best to do so. If you have a third option that I, deliriously writing this ramble at 2:30 AM, seem to have forgotten, please indicate it in an answer, too.

Comment: I feel sorry for @Deusovi. He has a about 7 puzzles in that list of 53

Comment: @Beastly Don't feel sorry for him - when those posts get edited and bumped to the top, he's going to get drive-by upvotes.

Comment: Worth noting that the query doesn't update due to data's limitations.

Comment: [Apparently](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/143/revisions) Community is [helping out](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/227/revisions). Nice of her, I must say.

Comment: The link in https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/multilayer-image-steganography is already broken.

Comment: @boboquack It looks like that puzzle used someone's personal Google Drive...

Comment: Hey, have they all been fixed? Your Data.SE query is showing nothing remaining after the weekly update.

Comment: @randal'thor P...ossibly. I think this is true. I'll keep an ear to the ground for news from Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Emrakul [Aaaaaaargh.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292234/278659) The query doesn't work any more. We need another one in order to find the broken images now.

Comment: (Although oddly enough, it *does* still seem to work [on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzlingme/query/430352/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2014-05-14&EndDate=2017-03-08).)

Comment: @Emrakul Do you have the CSV still? If so, can you please release it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Slow and steady wins the race.

Let's do these edits slowly over a more extended period. That way, we avoid pushing new puzzles off the front page so they're less likely to be seen, as well as the "stepping on each other's toes" issues that are likely to arise if we have several users trying to edit all of these posts all at once.

> Editing them slowly is more likely to lose interest, or take some serious dedication and restraint on the part of Friendly Citizens. But unless we truly dedicate to it, there's a possibility it may not be done before the change.

**I volunteer as tribute!**

Seriously, if we have a few weeks to make 53 edits, I could even do them all on my own. A few edits per day to old posts is nowhere near enough to mess up the front page, and I'm regularly reviewing old posts anyway, to edit or vote or flag or whatever. But I'm sure other upstanding PSE citizens will volunteer to help out (perhaps in the comments below this answer?) This can be done smoothly and efficiently, and all 53 will be fixed before you know what's happened.

Comment: This *is* a slightly easier task than on SFF... (I'll help edit the images, as I'm sure you're expecting :P)

Comment: Oops. I just did a few without reading this answer. Sorry.

Comment: @Techidiot Five edits at a time by a single user is a reasonable maximum, IMO. (Over at SFF, we have a guideline that no more than five of the top fifteen posts on the front page should be last edited by the same user.) What with my two and your five, let's give it a rest for a while now and let those questions sink down off the active questions list.

Comment: Yeah. Lets hold off.

Comment: Happy to help too. Maybe we should create a Google sheet to split the work into weekly/daily chunks. Each volunteer fixes one question per day/week at a random time convenient to them and marks it done in the sheet...?

Comment: +1 for the Google sheet

Comment: @Alconja Eh, we're unlikely to be stepping on each other's toes with edits if we're only doing a few a day. We could just keep a list of the 53 posts in this here meta answer and then edit them out as they're fixed.

Comment: @Sconibulus is also doing http→https edits. It's not just you three.  I was about to start doing a few myself until I saw this post wasn't just "hey, go do this", but was more "hey, how should we do this so we don't flood the site with edits"

Comment: @Rubio If you see anyone mass-editing loads of these in one go, do ping them in chat (or ask a chat mod to superping, if they're not pingable in tSL) pointing them to this meta post and asking them to ease off for a bit.

Comment: @randal'thor not really about treading on toes, more about keeping track so you don't go looking for things to fix and find it already done. Having a post here is fine too, just figured a google sheet is less painful to edit.

Comment: Okay, let's do it this way. Is this something you want to do? Do you think you're gonna need any help? (If so, I'd be happy to do so, or there are people who seem ready to!)

Comment: @Emrakul I'm happy to do it, but also happy to be part of a team doing it. May as well let other people work towards their Copy Editor and Archaeologist badges too ;-) Perhaps with both these image fixes and the tag changes being suggested over [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5844/5373), we have enough to organise a mass editing event? (This weekend is Mass Editing time over at SFF, and the number of questions we need to edit by hand is in the ***thousands***, so a) Puzzling should count itself lucky! and b) I'm kind of knackered from editing right now.)

Comment: @randal'thor Good lord that sure is a number of questions. I'll throw the idea into the mod chat for Puzzling, but I'm not sure we have quiiiite enough questions to warrant it here.